# Adding ASPX lines through aspx.cs

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I have an aspx website that is linked to an Access database. I want to generate cards, for each cards it contains a specific data from the database
(I want each row to be a card). so I need the number of cards to be synced with the number of rows of the db table.
So I thought to add the lines through the aspx.cs file but I can't figure out a way.

+I thought of `Response.Write()` but it isn't effective.

Comment: Do you mean that the data queried from the database is dynamically displayed on the page through the Response.Write() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproduced your problem by using the Repeater control. Use the Repeater control to bind the database to display each row of data in the database.You can refer to [repeater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater?view=netframework-4.8).

UI page:
[image]

Binding data source steps:

1. Select the Repeater control and click "New Data Source".

[image]

[image]

2. The next step is to bind the data source.

Click ok and then click new connection

[image]

Click Add Connection, and then write out the configuration of the relevant data source such as host name, database.

[image]

Click ok and then click next until this page appears, select the table you need to display the data.

[image]

The binding of the data source is complete.

This is the result displayed for each row of the table:

[image]

[image]

The aspx code of the ui page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <p>Name: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"> 
   </asp:TextBox>&nbsp&nbsp<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="confirm" OnClick="Button1_Click" /> </p>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  >
         <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="Student">
                <div class="inf">
                    <h3><%# Eval("Name") %> (<%# Eval("ID") %>)</h3>
                    <p>ID: <%#Eval("ID") %></p>
                    <p>Name: <%#Eval("Name") %></p>
                    <p>Department: <%#Eval("Department") %></p>
                    <p>ClassName: <%#Eval("ClassName") %></p>
                    <p>Age: <%#Eval("Age") %></p>
                    <p>Sex: <%#Eval("Sex").ToString() == "true" ? "male" : "female" %></p>
                </div>
         
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:studentConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [student_inf]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
```

Click the confirm button to enter the name to display the data of the corresponding row in the database table.

[image]

This is the code logic of the confirm button event, which implements the data of the corresponding row of the display table:

```
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         //The first step: construct the SQL statement of the query
         var CommandString = "select * from student_inf where Name Like '%{0}%'";

         CommandString = string.Format(CommandString, TextBox1.Text.Trim());

         //Step 2: Send the query SQL statement to the data source
         SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = CommandString;

         //Step 3: Rebind the data source to the Reactor control
         Repeater1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource1.ID;
         Repeater1.DataBind();//Data binding
     }
```

Hope it helps you.